# converting java hashMap to another hashMap by grouping some fields

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I hava a map like that(keys are customer number 1,2,3,4 etc..

```
Map<Long,List<Customer>> customerMap = new HashMap<Long, List<Customer>>();

public class Customer {
  private String name;
  private BigDecimal salary;

 //..getter and setters
```

I want to convert it to another map by grouping Name field.What i want to create map like that

```
Map<Long,Map<String,CustomerSalary>> convertedMap = new HashMap<Long,Map<String,CustomerSalary>>()();

public class CustomerSalary {
  private BigDecimal salary;
  private BigDecimal remainingSalary;

  //getter and setters.
```

What i did is

```
 `Map<Long,Map<String,CustomerSalary>> convertedMap =customerMap.entrySet()..stream() 
                .collect(Collectors.toMap( //collect the entries into another map
                    entry -> entry.getKey(), 
                    entry -> entry.getValue().stream()
                       .collect(groupingBy(Customer::getName,
                        reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Customer::getSalary, BigDecimal::add)))
                 ));
```

but not working because CustomerSalary should be but reducing creates BigDecimal.Do you have any idea?

Not:Salary and remainingSalary should be same initially.

Comment: If you're grouping by name, the value type would need to be a list.

Comment: @shmosel I also  want to sum salary.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to sum `salary`, you can use the `reducing()` collector:

```
entry.getValue().stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Customer::getName,
                reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Customer::getSalary, BigDecimal::add)))
```

If you want the result as a `CustomerSalary`, you can add similar operators to your class or sum and wrap via `collectingAndThen()`.

Comment: I updated my question but It is not working reducing method is undefined :(

Comment: @tom Compiles for me: https://ideone.com/Ck6Rpf

Comment: Thank you very much.It is working but I want return type like that `Map<Long,Map<String,CustomerSalary>>`

Comment: I addressed that.

Comment: Thank you I put the pieces together and working:)

Comment: I get Type mismatch: `cannot convert from Map<Object,Object> to Map<Long,Map<String,CustomerSalary >>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```java
Map<Long, Map<String, CustomerSalary>> collect =
    customerMap.entrySet().stream()
               .collect(toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                              e -> e.getValue()
                                    .stream()
                                    .collect(groupingBy(Customer::getName,
                                                        collectingAndThen(reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, Customer::getSalary, BigDecimal::add),      
                                                            s -> {                                                                                               
                                                                CustomerSalary salary = new CustomerSalary();                                                                                               
                                                                salary.setSalary(s);                                                      
                                                                salary.setRemainingSalary(s);                                                   
                                                                return salary;
                                                            })))));
```